# Richfaces tags not rendered

Tags: richfaces

I am trying to add richfaces capabilities to my JSF based web application, but none of the JSF tags are being rendered. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

I am using mojarra-2.0.3-FCS for JSF and richfaces 4.3.4

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>rich</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

richTest.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<f:view>
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <rich:panel header="TESTING">

            <ul>
                <li>RichFaces is a component library for JSF</li>
                <li>easily integrating AJAX capabilities.</li>
            </ul>
        </rich:panel>

    </h:body>
</f:view>

</ui:composition>
```

source of rendered page:

```
<head></head>
<body>
        <rich:panel header="TESTING">

            <ul>
                <li>RichFaces is a component library for JSF</li>
                <li>easily integrating AJAX capabilities.</li>
            </ul>
        </rich:panel>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried that but there is no change in the output, I am adding the source of the output page. By the way, according to [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html) , there is no need to add any configuration in web.xml.

Comment: The configuration looks OK, I wonder if it something to do with mojarra version or deployment. Could you try more recent version of JSF? What application server are you using?

Comment: Hi Andrey, I actually tried to setup a new project with the same configuration and it seems to work fine. However I am not able to make it work with the current project which I have. By the way, my current project is EJB client with web interface. And to answer your question, I am using glassfish 3.1.